# Unity: What is actually needed to make RegisterInstance work?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, prism, uwp

So, I'm using Prism and Prism.Unity to build my app. However, I'm running into an issue I haven't been able to find documentation on. It's probably quite basic but the error message is not so helpful and the stack trace doesn't help either.

So, basically, when registering an instance of an existing object, I'm supposed to simply do this, according to the docs I found:

```
EmailService myEmailService = new EmailService();
myContainer.RegisterInstance<IMyService>(myEmailService);
```

I'm following that to the letter, the class and interface in question are currently empty, though, so kind of like this:

```
interface IMyService { }
class EmailService : IMyService { }
```

Now, when the app is executing the commands above, it throws an exception at RegisterInstance() with the following message:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: container
```

So, where does this go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I actually found the answer. Basically, I had stuffed the registration of the instance into the App.App() routine (which is treated as the equivalent of main() in UWP), after the `this.InitializeComponent();`

After thinking about the error message some more (and seeing that the error message came from an `IEnumerable.Any()`, so something like `<null>.Any()` was the actual source, I thought to myself:

What if `InitializeComponent()` has yet stuff to finish and the UnityContainer hasn't been fully constructed?

So, I shoved the registration into the `OnLaunchApplicationAsync()` routine like this:

```
protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    EmailService myEmailService = new EmailService();
    Container.RegisterInstance<IMyService>(myEmailService);
    NavigationService.Navigate("Main", null);
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

And now it works. As I said, basic stuff. Damn.

Comment: If you check the samples in the Prism repo, you'll see that you have following override where you could place that code: `protected override void ConfigureContainer()`

Comment: Or that, yes. Thanks.